Is it legal in the United Kingdom to discriminate on hiring due to business dealings with sanctioned countries?
I've had a qualified candidate apply to one of my job postings.  He is Iranian with indefinite leave to remain in the UK.  However he has a business interest in Iran where he sells VPNs with bitcoin to circumvent Iranian internet censorship.
I have absolutely no problem with this.  But this is compliance nightmare where he probably manages non-KYC crypto funds from Iran.
He's a young graduate, and I would like to be honest why we're not going to hire him, and explain that this will stop him from getting a job in UK financial firms.  But I don't want the liability of a discrimination case.

"Compliance" doesn't sound like a personal feeling. Is it your corporate lawyer approved corporate guideline to not hire them based on those facts, or not? If it is, ask those lawyers whether you are free to tell people about those guidelines. We cannot decide that for you.

It was more compliances refusal to even look at the candidate because of the work involved.

You will have to check with your lawyers, if this is legal. Even if we had a super expert here who is magically able to ascertain the "absolute truth", if your company's lawyers say something else, it will be on you. Your company doesn't care for "rando on the internet", no matter how legally correct they might be. They care for what their own lawyers say. I'm not voting to close, I do think that there can be valid legal information here, all I'm saying is, don't act on it, if you value your job. Act on what your company lawyers tell you.

Offering support to someone you know is breaching OFSI sanctions could be an offence. Tread carefully.

It is unlawful to discriminate against a candidate because of their national origin. It is not unlawful to discriminate against a candidate on the grounds of their hobby, 'side-hustle' or job on the side.
